# What's the right required meta-tag for retagging requests?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, per-site-meta, required-tags

Of the required meta tags ([bug](/questions/tagged/bug), [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion),  [support](/questions/tagged/support)), which is most appropriate for retagging requests?

Comment: Use `support` or `discussion` but not both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I go with `[support]` + `[retag-request]` and all of the relevent `[(site name)]` tags.

Comment: `[(site name)]` is almost *always* applicable.  tags aren't really synced between sites.  there's some manual effort to do that, which is good, but even on a cross-site retag request you'd want to tag with all sites so that the folks who do the batch-retags can find your tag request with a search like this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag-request+superuser

Comment: @quack: Yes, good point. Updated my answer.